# referencing foreign key attributes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scaffold VirtualTransaction referencing my User model.

virtual_transaction.rb

```
class VirtualTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :buyer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'buyer_id'
  has_one :seller, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'seller_id'
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :virtual_transactions
end
```

But I can't take any further steps to access the association.

I get:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column 
users.buyer_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."buyer_id" = $1...
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."buyer_id" = $1 LIMIT $2
from (irb):7
```

when I try to do:

```
virtual_transaction=VirtualTransaction.first
virtual_transaction.buyer
```

All I intend to do is access the name of the user referencing the buyer/seller id and display it in my view.

```
VirtualTransaction(id: integer, buyer_id: integer, seller_id: integer, amount: decimal, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `belongs_to` instead of `has_one` as your association.  That will cause ActiveRecord to look for the `buyer_id` foreign key in the `virtual_transactions` table:

```
class VirtualTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'buyer_id'
  belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'seller_id'
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. But when I try to do <%= @virtual_transaction.buyer.first_name %> it still gives me the buyer.id integer value lol. What am I missing here?

Comment: I would have to see how `@virtual_transaction` is being set to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `buyer_id` as your table column to store the reference, and postgresql can't find that column.
I don't know your table structure, but you can add a column for foreign key in that case like this:

```
rails g migration AddBuyerIdToVirtualTransaction buyer_id:integer
```

Also, you said your scaffold is called `VirtualTransaction`, but in the piece of code you pasted, the class is name only `Transaction`.

I think you doing some mistake with the names of your tables/columns. If you post more details about that, we could help better. Good luck

Comment: sorry that's a typo on my part, it is VirtualTransaction. Also my scaffold was rails g scaffold buyer_id:integer seller_id:integer amount:decimal. So I think the tables are set correctly.

Comment: @Solias no problem. Also it would be good to paste your Models columns. You can check them on rails console calling the model name

Comment: when I query virtual_transaction.buyer_id I get the right value (that is, whatever I've created as a record). But with the association I have created I should be able to access virtual_transaction.buyer too right? To retrieve the user's name. 
EDIT: Yeah, I posted the model columns in the main post.

Comment: @Solias try to change has_one to belongs_to as Tom Aranda suggested so